# Installing packages on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum, repository

My question is not even a problem I have. Probably someone can explain what is the principal difference between following commands for installing a package (in my case htop) at CentOS 7.

1. `# yum --enablerepo=epel install htop`
2. `# yum install htop`

I've been using simple `yum install htop` as it's less to type. Everything seems to be working, but my friend uses the first option, and I was wondering is there something inherently wrong I am doing by using the second option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first command, `yum --enable-repo=epel`, overrides the setting in the `.repo` while it is being run. In this case, if it's disabled, the setting will enable it while installing the specific package. If he has the EPEL repo disabled and wants to install a package from it, then he'll need to use that command or else he'd have to run `yum-config-manager --enable repo`, `yum install <package>`, and then `yum-config-manager --disable repo` or edit the .repo file before and after installing the package which would be incredibly tedious.

Your system has the EPEL repo enabled so you can just use `yum install package`.

If your friend has EPEL enabled in the repo file, then there's no reason for him to use that command and he can just use the second one with no issues.